# Python- How to use csv.writer with out quotation

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a list which whose contents have to be written to a csv file, with out quotation.

The contents of the list is as shown below:

```
list=[(1, 2, 1), (1, 3, 1), (1, 4, 1), (1, 5, 1), (2, 1, 1), (2, 3, 1), (2, 4, 1), (2, 5, 1), (3, 1, 1), (3, 2, 1), (3, 4, 1), (3, 5, 1), (4, 1, 1), (4, 2, 1), (4, 3, 1), (4, 5, 1), (5, 1, 1), (5, 2, 1), (5, 3, 1), (5, 4, 1)]
```

Now i have the below two code snippet which tries to write this list to a csv file:

**Method 1:**

def method1():

```
list=[(1, 2, 1), (1, 3, 1), (1, 4, 1), (1, 5, 1), (2, 1, 1), (2, 3, 1), (2, 4, 1), (2, 5, 1), (3, 1, 1), (3, 2, 1), (3, 4, 1), (3, 5, 1), (4, 1, 1), (4, 2, 1), (4, 3, 1), (4, 5, 1), (5, 1, 1), (5, 2, 1), (5, 3, 1), (5, 4, 1)]
myfile = open('output.csv', 'w')
        wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE, delimiter=',', escapechar=',')
        wr.writerow(list)
```

The contents of the csv file are as shown below:

```
(1,, 2,, 1),(1,, 3,, 1),(1,, 4,, 1),(1,, 5,, 1),(2,, 1,, 1),(2,, 3,, 1),(2,, 4,, 1),(2,, 5,, 1),(3,, 1,, 1),(3,, 2,, 1),(3,, 4,, 1),(3,, 5,, 1),(4,, 1,, 1),(4,, 2,, 1),(4,, 3,, 1),(4,, 5,, 1),(5,, 1,, 1),(5,, 2,, 1),(5,, 3,, 1),(5,, 4,, 1)
```

I do not want the "," in between the elements of the list. If i remove the escapechar form the above code, it throws me an error.

The error is:

***_csv.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set***

**Method 2:**

def method2():

```
list=[(1, 2, 1), (1, 3, 1), (1, 4, 1), (1, 5, 1), (2, 1, 1), (2, 3, 1), (2, 4, 1), (2, 5, 1), (3, 1, 1), (3, 2, 1), (3, 4, 1), (3, 5, 1), (4, 1, 1), (4, 2, 1), (4, 3, 1), (4, 5, 1), (5, 1, 1), (5, 2, 1), (5, 3, 1), (5, 4, 1)]
myfile = open('output.csv', 'wb')
        wr = csv.writer(myfile)
        wr.writerow(list)
```

The output of method 2 is as shown below:

"(1, 2, 1)","(1, 3, 1)","(1, 4, 1)","(1, 5, 1)","(2, 1, 1)","(2, 3, 1)","(2, 4, 1)","(2, 5, 1)","(3, 1, 1)","(3, 2, 1)","(3, 4, 1)","(3, 5, 1)","(4, 1, 1)","(4, 2, 1)","(4, 3, 1)","(4, 5, 1)","(5, 1, 1)","(5, 2, 1)","(5, 3, 1)","(5, 4, 1)"

Could anybody help me out with the issue?

The contents of my output file must look like this:

```
(1, 2, 1), 
(1, 3, 1), 
(1, 4, 1), 
(1, 5, 1),

...
...
```

Comment: if that is your output format, I don't see much advantage of using the `csv` module.

Comment: @monkut could you please let me know how i could do this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need csv at all, look at this:

```
>>> list=[(1, 2, 1), (1, 3, 1), (1, 4, 1), (1, 5, 1), (2, 1, 1), (2, 3, 1), (2, 4, 1), (2, 5, 1), (3, 1, 1), (3, 2, 1), (3, 4, 1), (3, 5, 1), (4, 1, 1), (4, 2, 1), (4, 3, 1), (4, 5, 1), (5, 1, 1), (5, 2, 1), (5, 3, 1), (5, 4, 1)]
>>> with open('out.txt', 'w') as out:
...     for t in list:
...         out.write(str(t)+",\n")
... 
>>> 
host:~$ head out.txt 
(1, 2, 1),
(1, 3, 1),
(1, 4, 1),
(1, 5, 1),
(2, 1, 1),
(2, 3, 1),
(2, 4, 1),
(2, 5, 1),
(3, 1, 1),
(3, 2, 1),
```

Answer (score 2):

The format you describe doesn't seem to require the `csv` module.  You can just write out the format using something like this:

```
list=[(1, 2, 1), (1, 3, 1), (1, 4, 1), (1, 5, 1), (2, 1, 1), (2, 3, 1), (2, 4, 1), (2, 5, 1), (3, 1, 1), (3, 2, 1), (3, 4, 1), (3, 5, 1), (4, 1, 1), (4, 2, 1), (4, 3, 1), (4, 5, 1), (5, 1, 1), (5, 2, 1), (5, 3, 1), (5, 4, 1)]

with open("output.csv", "w") as out_f:
    for item in list:
        output_str = "{},\n".format(item)
        out_f.write(output_str)
```

Comment: awesome, thank you for the quick reply! One more question, could you please let me know when i would have to use the csv module and when not to? Considering the above case, i was struggling a lot!